# continuous integration for updating the Conda- Forge feedstock

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pypi, conda-forge

How to setup a CI pipeline for continuous integration to update the feedstock ?
I want to set up a way for new releases to also be pushed to conda-forge just like they are automatically for PyPI. Actually I have found few repositories which might be helpful.

First we need to stage the package through this repo
https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes

Then Continuous integration pipeline needs to be staged up for the feedstock but since I don't have much that deep idea into DevOps  could not understand which of these two repositories will be used to setup the CI pipeline

https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-ci-setup-feedstock

https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-smithy

so I would appreciate if anyone can guide me through this

Comment: After your recipe has been approved and merged into the `staged-recipes` repo, conda-forge will automatically create a new feedstock repo for your package.  Then, every time you push a new release tag to your own git repo (or push a new PyPI package), a conda-forge bot will automatically create a PR on the feedstock repo to build the new package version.  conda-forge's own CI system will run the build and generate the packages.  If it builds successfully, all you have to do is click the "merge" button to publish the updated packages on the `conda-forge` channel.

Answer (score 6):

Step 1 : build a PyPi package and upload it (I think you already did that)

Step 2 : install grayskull : `conda install -c conda-forge grayskull`, the [grayskull repo](https://github.com/conda-incubator/grayskull) shows how to generate a `conda recipe` called 'meta.yaml' directly from your package on PyPi

Step 3 : Fork `conda-forge/staged-recipes` in your user/organization space.

Step 4 : go into the `recipes` directory, and make a directory in it with the name of your project.

Step 5 : add the `meta.yaml` created in step 2 to `recipes/your-project-name/`

Step 6 : add your LICENSE file to `recipes/your-project-name/`

Step 7 : do a PR against `conda-forge/staged-recipes`

Step 8 : wait until it is approved (and be patient) ;-)

Once you have a feedstock you could edit the GitHub workflow, but the `automerge` workflow should be there, meaning that the `regro-cf-autotick-bot` will create a PR to your feedstock whenever a new package is detected on PyPi, and that PR is merged automatically :-)

In other words: once you have a feedstock, your project repo's CD just need to push to PyPi, and a while later your new release will also pop up on `conda-forge`.